# Ошибка htaccess php

Tags: php, .htaccess

Пишет error 500, что не так?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA, L]
```

Comment: 500 - ошибка в скриптах php. включай отображение ошибок

Comment: Может, у вас в коде файла index.php ошибка, которая выдает 500. Гадать на кофейной гуще?

Comment: <?php
    use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;
    use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;
    use Slim\Factory\AppFactory;
    require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

    $app = AppFactory::create();

    $app->get('/', function (ServerRequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response){
        $response->getBody()->write('Home page');
        return $response;
    });

    $app->get('/login', function (ServerRequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response){
        $response->getBody()->write('Login page');
        return $response;
 });
 $app->run();

Comment: Когда убираю .htaccess файл, все норм

Comment: RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA, L]

RewriteRule is invalid, does it contain a space in the pattern or the substitution? Пишет первый попавшийся валидатор.

Comment: @void, thanks, there was a space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так надо. А у вас лишний пробел был в последней строчке. Любой валидатор покажет ошибку.

```
RewriteEngine On
Rewrite Cond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, все сработало